# php notice, sql and isset()

Tags: php, sql, notice

how can i get rid of the apache/php message "Notice: Undefined index" in an sql query string:

Using @ it works `$query .= "     hash = '" . @$_GET['key'] . "'";`

but with isset() it doesn't:
`$query .= "     hash = '" . !isset($_GET['key']) . "'";`

and at the if clause:

Using @ it works
`if (@$_GET['action'] === "de") {`

but with isset() it doesn't:
`if (!isset($_GET['action']) === "de") {`

Thanks for your help

Comment: rather than trying to eliminate the message, try fixing the issue

Comment: FYI: `isset` return boolean, you cant check that it is set AND contains the 'de' without doing as Andrius has said below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @ operator just tells the interpreter to shut up and ignore errors that will not crash the system. It gives an unstable code, and should not be used!

The function [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns `true`or `false`. You use it to check if a variable is declared and has a value. This is how you should use it:

```
$query .= "hash = '" . ( isset($_GET['key']) ? $_GET['key'] : '' ) . "'";
```

This means use `$_GET['key']` if it is declared and has a value otherwise use the default value ('').

Sometimes the code can run with a default value, if nothing is supplied. This is one use of isset().

Above, I use a short version of `if ... else`. The two statements below are the same:

```
// Short version ( TEST ? if TRUE : else FALSE )
$query = isset($_GET['key']) ? $_GET['key'] : '';

// Long version
if ( isset( $_GET['key'] ) )
    $query = $_GET['key'];
else
    $query = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do in this case is use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php). And only after that check the value:

```
if (array_key_exists('action',$_GET) && $_GET['action'] === "de") {
...
}
```

That way, if the first one fails, the second is never checked and you won't get the notice.

You should **NEVER use @** in serious code.

Comment: Great answer here, really helpful and good practice going on, I like this a lot!

Comment: Guys you are great and so fast in responding, thanks.

Comment: You should NEVER use @ in serious code. That is why i am asking. @ makes to code looking quick and dirty

Answer (score 0):

You should try to fix your code rather than trying to avoid it. You should always check for a value before trying to use it. i.e

```
if(!isset($_GET['key'])&&!empty($_GET['key'])){
    return 'action isnt set!';
};
```

Comment: There is another check that you have missed from your answer, in the question, the OP uses `if (!isset($_GET['action'] === "de")`, your version would be incomplete for the OP

Comment: @SamSwift웃, i was just generalising, there is no specific answer for these type of questions. Not  even one.

Comment: Thanks for all comments and suggestions. I understand now how it should be used.